# Loop through an Array and access their properties in JavaScript in IE

Tags: javascript

I would like to use the same alert message to display all the messages at once.

```js
function LoadData(obj) {
    var ArrayData = $('input[type="hidden"][id^="li"]').map(function() {
        return this.getAttribute("value");
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        data: {
            GUID: JSON.stringify(ArrayData)
        },
        url: "/LoadOrder/LoadData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.length > 0) {
                for (var item of result) {
                    alert("There are problems with your selections ${item.Desc} and ${item.EDesc}
.");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Expected result should be displayed like below only once.

Currently, the same message displays 3 times.

```
There are problems with your selections.

ABC - CDE

GFE- Test

Test1 - Test2
```

Is there any way to display all in once.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `success` callback so that you first create the list of messages as a string and then call the `alert`

```js
success: function(result) {
  if (result.length > 0) {
    const problems = result.map(item => `${item.Desc} - ${item.EDesc}`).join('\n');
    alert(`There are problems with your selections.\n${problems}`);
  }
}
```

and without using arrow functions

```js
success: function(result) {
  if (result.length > 0) {
    var problems = result.map(function(item) {
      return `${item.Desc} - ${item.EDesc}`
    }).join('\n');
    alert(`There are problems with your selections.\n${problems}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gabriele Petroli, Can you please use normal function to support in IE. This arrow function does not support in IE

Comment: @testtest sure, added a version without using arrow functions.